# org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLogger cannot be cast to java.util.logging.Logger

Tags: java

I am trying to run the denclue algoritm but I faced with below error .I dont know how can i solve this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at test.ReadStringFromFileLineByLine.main(ReadStringFromFileLineByLine.java:83)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLogger cannot be cast to java.util.logging.Logger
    at smile.clustering.DENCLUE.<clinit>(DENCLUE.java:33)
    ... 1 more
```

I use these three jar files:

log4j-1.2.17.jar

slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar

slf4j-nop-1.7.10.jar

What should I do?
please help me!

Ok this is my whole code infact in this project I read the text file and change it to the 2d array and then call the denclue class algorithm.
ReadStringFromFileLineByLine is the name of this class.

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.omg.CORBA.PUBLIC_MEMBER;


import smile.clustering.DENCLUE;

public class ReadStringFromFileLineByLine {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
         System.out.println(t1);

        try {
            File file = new File("E:/spam.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            int numberOfLines=Readfile.readLines();
            int i=0;
            int k=0;
            String[] aryLines =new String[numberOfLines];
            int j=0;
            double[] txtData1d =new    double[aryLines.length];
             double[][] txtData2d =new double[(txtData1d.length)/2][(txtData1d.length)/2];
            System.out.println("aryLines");

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                aryLines[i]=line;
                String[] words=aryLines[i].split("    ");

                i++;

                for (String s : words)
                {

                    for(int a=0; a<(txtData1d.length)/2; a++){//convert 1d to 2d
                        for(int b=0; b<(txtData1d.length)/2; b++){


                           // k++;



                        }



                    }


                }

            }
            System.out.println("after loops");



                for(int a=0; a<(txtData1d.length)/2; a++){//convert 1d to 2d
                for(int b=0; b<(txtData1d.length)/2; b++){

                    txtData2d[a][b] = txtData1d[k];
                   k++;
                }
                }

               DENCLUE vbbx= new DENCLUE(txtData2d,0.5 , 12); 

            fileReader.close();
            System.out.println("Contents of file:");

            System.out.println(vbbx.toString());
            long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Time in milliseconds: " + (t2 - t1));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Ok this is [copyrighted code removed]

I add org.slf4j.Logger and the last error finished but I faced the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at smile.clustering.BBDTree.buildNode(BBDTree.java:110)
    at smile.clustering.BBDTree.<init>(BBDTree.java:103)
    at smile.clustering.KMeans.<init>(KMeans.java:82)
    at smile.clustering.KMeans.<init>(KMeans.java:72)
    at smile.clustering.DENCLUE.<init>(DENCLUE.java:98)
    at test.ReadStringFromFileLineByLine.main(ReadStringFromFileLineByLine.java:83)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full source code of the `ReadStringFromFileLineByLine` class. It looks like you are have a wrong import statement, which points to `java.util.logging`. Since you are using SLF4J, you should remove it.

Comment: ok I add the whole code.

Comment: Please add the class `DENCLUE` as well and check the imports of that class as well.

Comment: I add denclue algorithm.Now what should I do?

Comment: As @juwil already answered, remove the `java.util.logging.Logger` import, you are using SLF4J instead.

Comment: @Progman as DENCLUE is not his code, asking for a *link* to that source would have been more appropriate. (Google smile DENCLUE github).

Answer (score 1):

instead of java.util.logging.Logger you might use org.slf4j.Logger. Just change your import accordingly.

Comment: what shoud i do?

Comment: remove `import java.util.logging.Logger;` and instead write `import org.slf4j.Logger`. Thats it.

Comment: I add org.slf4j.Logger and the last error finished but I faced the below error:   Exception in thread "main"java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0